# Браузер не принимает самоподписанный сертификат

Tags: c#, https, ssl, proxy, tls

Я пишу HTTPS Proxy (наподобие Fiddler, только для конкретного домена). Соответственно, для просмотра зашифрованного трафика нужно организовать передачу браузеру сертификата с совпадающим именем нужного домена. Сертификат предварительно установлен как доверенный, т.к. является самоподписанным (через Мастер импорта сертификатов Windows; просмотреть можно в настройках сертификатов браузера в списках Личные и Доверенные корневые центры сертификации). Однако, при попытке соединения браузер даёт ошибку `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` и пишет что соединение не защищено.

Код аутентификации:

```
client = serverSock.Accept();
clientSslStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(client));
clientSslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCert); // X509Certificate2 from correct PFX file.
```

В адресной строке указано, что сертификат не действителен, но если там же открыть настройки переданного сертификата, то в окне свойств пишется, что сертификат действителен. Хм...

P.S.: Использую Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

`ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` говорит о том, что сертификат вы сделали не для того домена или сайта, к которому пытаетесь подключиться.

[Chrome последних версий не смотрит на `commonName`, а смотрит только на `subjectAltName`.](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/IGT2fLJrAeo) Если вы при создании сертификата через конфиг не указываете SAN, то вы получаете такую ошибку.

Comment: В том то и дело, что имена совпадают.

Comment: Имя домена и имя указанное в сертификате

Comment: В поле subjectAltName?

Comment: Нет. Вот сейчас пытаюсь собирать сертификат с таким полем. Использую OpenSSL. Сертификат без этого поля собрать не составило труда, но каким образом можно его добавить даже не знаю. Вроде как нужно что-то менять в CFG файле, что лежит в одной папке с openssl.exe (вот как он у меня выглядит: http://web.mit.edu/crypto/openssl.cnf). Где именно нужно указать `subjectAltName`?